# Как при соединении массива пропустить пустые значения?

Tags: javascript

```js
let arr = [1, 2, , 4, , 6];

console.log( arr.join('/') );
```

Comment: Сделайте проверку и пропускайте соединение

Comment: @Алексей, я знаю что можно циклом проверить, типа такого `arr.filter(e => e).join('/')`, но из за больших массивов очень медленно обрабатывается. Есть еще какие нибудь варианты?

Comment: только самому проверять и объединять. можно уложиться в один цикл

Answer (score 1):

Метод [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) пропускает пустые элементы:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, , 4, , 6];
console.log(arr.reduce((acc, cur)=>`${acc}/${cur}`));
```